# MS CRM 2011 - New Polaris UI - how can I get it?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

How can I get the new Polaris UI that was supposed to be released December? I heard it was released then was recalled. How can I access a beta copy for a client demo?

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to the "On-Premise" version, then this has not yet been released.

For client demos, you could sign up for a [free 30-day trial for CRM Online](http://crm.dynamics.com/en-gb/trial-overview) (no credit card details needed). Since around mid-January, all CRM Online trials are automatically preloaded with the Polaris updates.

Answer (score 0):

The Rollup 12 (v2) for CRM 2011 On-Premise has just been re-released. 
Check it out

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36229

Comment: The new UI is not part of the Update Rollup 12. It will be released later this year for On-Premise

Comment: "Damn that's bad news" - actually it might be a blessing in disguise

Comment: I think you're assuming that the newer version the better. UR12 had huge issues and there's been a lot of upset discussions of which I'm not supposed to know anything so I can't give you any details. But I agree with @AdamV. Be glad it's delayed.

Answer (score 0):

The update roll-up 12 has been released and taken back due to bugs.

However, if you go to crm.dynamics.com and register for a free CRM On-line account (that will last you for four weeks before you need to pay), you'll get what you wish.

It's my understanding that the biggest change is the process driven UI that is supposed to substitute the forms. Haven't tried it out, yet, but it looks interesting.

Frankly, I was expecting more visual changes in the the version so I'm a little bit disappointed. But it's definitely a step in right direction!